# $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and php://input stream Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi there I just got this error today using php5.6 and Laravel 5.2

Error:

> Deprecated: Automatically populating `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set `'always_populate_raw_post_data'` to `'-1'` in `php.ini` and use the `php://input` stream instead. in Unknown on line 0

The Part I don't understand is *"use the `php://input` stream instead. in Unknown on line 0"*

I am still getting this error and the second part I don't understand with the php://input stream

> Deprecated: Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in Unknown on line 0
>   {"supplier_id":["Please choose a supplier"],"category_id":["The category id field is required."],"brand_id":["Please choose a brand"],"keywords":["The keywords field is required."],"sku":["The sku field is required."],"quantity":["The quantity field is required."],"unit_price":["The unit price field is required."],"sell_price":["The sell price field is required."],"weight":["The weight field is required."],"dimensions":["The dimensions field is required."],"title":["The title field is required."]}

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13883

Comment: I've changed the value to -1 but I'm still getting this error I don't know what to change or where to change the php:://input stream

Comment: Did you restart your web server (if using one)?

Comment: Yeah I did that I'm using wamp 32bit

Comment: If you can, go to PHP 7.0 or later. It doesn't have this wacky problem

Comment: I changed to 7.0 and I'm still getting the same error and I have restarted the server

Comment: check my error I've updated my question

Comment: Please refer to the documentation regarding `php://input` stream. http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php